# meet a problem when I used the a:nth-of-type(n) syntax

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to using beautiful soup, and I encounter an interesting problem
The code is following:

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>"happy new year"</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>c.biancheng.net</b></p>
<p class="website">2022 is last year</p>
<a href="http://c.biancheng.net/python/" id="link1">2023 is the new year</a>
<a href="http://c.biancheng.net/c/" id="link2">hope you will be better</a>
<a href="http://c.biancheng.net/django/" id="link3">achieve more</a>
<p class="VIP">YEAH</p>
<a href="http://vip.biancheng.net/?from=index" id="link4">and realize your dream</a>
<p class="introduce">introduction:
<a href="http://c.biancheng.net/view/8066.html" id="link5">best</a>
<a href="http://c.biancheng.net/view/8092.html" id="link6">wishes</a>
</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select('p ~ a:nth-of-type(4)'))
```

The above code will print

`[<a href="http://vip.biancheng.net/?from=index" id="link4">and realize your dream</a>]`

However, if I change 4 into 5, which looks like this:

```
print(soup.select('p ~ a:nth-of-type(5)'))
```

The return value will be [], which means None. But I have no idea how it comes. Could you tell me what happened?

Comment: The last two anchors are inside a paragraph element, and thus there is no fifth anchor directly at the same level as the first paragraph element. (Note how the line `<p class="introduce">introduction:` is only closed by `</p>` three lines below it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you tell me what happened?

There are only 4 `a` tags that are next-sibling to `p` tags. The last two `a` tags are *inside* the `p.introduce` element and have no previous-sibling `p` tags.

`soup.select('a:nth-of-type(1)')` would return

```html
[<a href="http://c.biancheng.net/python/" id="link1">2023 is the new year</a>,
 <a href="http://c.biancheng.net/view/8066.html" id="link5">best</a>]
```

and `soup.select('a:nth-of-type(2)')` would return

```html
[<a href="http://c.biancheng.net/c/" id="link2">hope you will be better</a>,
 <a href="http://c.biancheng.net/view/8092.html" id="link6">wishes</a>]
```

`html_doc` does not contain any `a:nth-of-type(5)` or `a:nth-of-type(6)` elements and contains only 4 `p~a` elements.
[image: opex]